# Trying to route parameters to catch all index action on home controller

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to capture parameters into the default home mvc controller which till now I didn't need to do as angular is taking care of all the views/routing.

The reason for this is because I was using angular to set metadata for the SEO. That doesn't work as angular is purely client side. The SEO has to come from the server.

My home controller route is simply this which is a catch all right now, so it needs to stay a catch all but also receive any extra parameters

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*.}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

So I can capture something in the url like this ie 'product'

```
public ActionResult Index(string product = "")
    {

        var meta = new MetaData
        {
            Title = "Test",
            Description = "Desc1",
            Keywords = ""
        };

        return View("Index",meta);
    }
```

I can't use something like

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

Because then it will expect views/controllers for my other pages which are taken care of by angular.

So I need a default route that will use the home controller whenever the url is like this

mywebsitename.com/showmen

I tried

```
 url: "*./{product}",
```

but that is invalid. I also changed the route to

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*.}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" , product = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: I have a solution to this, will be posting it shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the catch all route and just used a default one like this for the home page

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HomePage",
            url: "",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

Without the catch all I had to add quite a few routes for the other pages like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "LandingPage",
            url: "landingpage/{product}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Landing",
                product = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
       );
```

So now i can capture the product and send the metadata to _Layout using the same index view. Meanwhile the angular route still does what it did before.

Anything that receives a quoteref/password all use a generic route that passes to the home controller index action to update the same model on _Layout.